# Where does the Eclipse SQL Explorer Plugin store its preferences?

Tags: sql, eclipse, preferences

I've switched to Eclipse Juno, which claims not to support SQL Explorer. So I want to start using the stand-alone SQL Explorer, but I don't want to have to re-enter all my connections.

Where does the Eclipse SQL Explorer plugin save its settings, and where does the SQL Explorer stand-alone app store its settings, so I can copy them over?

Answer (score 3):

So, after some research, I have an answer.  The Exclipse SQL Explorer settings are stored in

```
<your-workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/net.sourceforge.sqlexplorer/
```

The same is true for SQL Explorer.  However, SQL Explorer doesn't give you any way to specify the "workspace" to use.  On the Mac, you need to "Show Package Contents" on the SQL Explorer app, then drill down to Contents/MacOS/ to find the workspace folder.

Comment: Just to be clear: on Mac/OS the SQLExplorer "workspace" is inside the MacOS folder